# Visual Studio Emulator for android wont start

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, config

I am trying to start a Visual Studio Emulator for android (Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 1), and I'm stuck. No matter what I do, it keeps prompting me:

> A valid license is required to run Visual Studio Emulator for Android
>   and no license was found. The application will not exit

I've tried:

1. Updated VS license
2. Opened emulator from VS
3. Tried to login through Start menu -> Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try updating the emulator? They just shipped an update. Also, make sure you have the latest emulator images.

Comment: What happens when you go to the Start Menu > Visual Studio Emulator for Android? Are you shown as logged in on the top right or prompted to log in? If you do have to log in, can you start a device profile?

Comment: No, I'm not shown as logged in, I'm trying to log in with my Microsoft account (same as on Visual Studio) but every time it throws we from the "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" with the message from the posted question

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug listed in the "known issues" for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC. We've since published an update to the emulator that fixes it. If you go to Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android... in Visual Studio 2015, the Emulator Manager will open, which will show an info bar prompting you to update. Thanks!